# Can I use this drain in wood subfloor?

Tags: plumbing, flooring

I am installing a drain in an upper floor laundry and had limited choices for floor drains.  I picked up this "general purpose" drain. The only other option was a shower drain.   It will be located under the clothes washer so not visible or in a high traffic area.  I would like it to sit flush or just below the floor surface which is why I did not select the "shower drain" which would have a bit of a lip.  Any good advice on installing this?  Is this not the right drain for wood subfloor?

I have not selected flooring or installed any underlayment yet. But if I have my way, it will be some type of marmoleum or vinyl sheet (will need to work on my sales pitch to the boss ;) )

[image]
[image]

Here is my current plan:
[image]

Comment: Do you anticipate that water (or other fluids) will be regularly on the floor?  Or is this basically for emergency drainage?

Comment: @wallyk It is an emergency drain only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  I have done a few drains on second floor laundry areas.  This is perfectly acceptable.

First you don't really pick where the drain goes exactly gravity does.  You need to figure out in what direction water will go in that room from the washer - you need to put it on the low point.  Then you need to chisel out slight the area around it - maybe going out a foot or two and down at least 1/16th of an inch, better if 1/8th.

Also if you are really worried about what is under the room you might want to redgard the floor or some other sort of waterproofing.

Comment: Thanks.  I just installed it today before reading this.  I did locate it on the low side of the floor and I took a belt sander with a very coarse belt to the underlayment.  I will look into redgard.  never heard of it.  Looks nice.  I had a floor once with vinyl that wrapped up the walls in lieu of trim.  might try to do that here.